# The input image lost its PixelFormat during the loading process. c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixelformat

I want to load an image from my resources to a Bitmap, and save its Pixel Format. The input image is a .bmp file with 8 BitsPerPixel image depth. This is the code:

```
Bitmap inputImage = new Bitmap(Test.Resources.sourceImage);
```

When I debug the program and I check the properties of the sourceImage, its PixelFormat is `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed`.
But after this variable assignment the PixelFormat of inputImage is `Format32bppArgb`.

Do you have any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var source = Test.Resources.sourceImage;
Bitmap inputImage = source.Clone(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, source.Size), source.PixelFormat);
```